# How to count someday to someday without holiday and Saturday , Sunday (VB) by use Date time picker

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeVeL.png)How to count someday to someday without holiday and Saturday , Sunday (VB) by use Date time picker

for leave people system
help me please!

from the picture 
left is date start and right is end date
then if I select date both. then count day on the textbox... without Sunday Saturday and Holiday that on Access database...

Comment: How do we know if it is a holiday?

Comment: Writing code is a good start...

Comment: I have holiday on Access database but I don't know to use it ... ><

Comment: We don't know either as you've given us no code nor any nudge how your database actually looks (is constructed).

Answer (score 0):

Count days from start to finish that are not Saturday or Sunday:

```
    Dim startDate As Date = New DateTime(2016, 1, 1)
    Dim endDate As Date = DateTime.Now
    Dim currentDate = startDate
    Dim daysWithoutSatOrSun As Integer = 0

    Do
        If currentDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso currentDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
            daysWithoutSatOrSun += 1
        End If
        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)
    Loop Until currentDate > endDate

    MessageBox.Show("Days " & daysWithoutSatOrSun)
```

Comment: If I have Holiday on database. How to I will use?

Answer (score 0):

One readable option is to use LINQ:

```
Dim days As Int32 = (d2 - d1).Days 
Dim weekend = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday }
Dim nonWeekendDays = From d in Enumerable.Range(0, days + 1)
                     Select day = d1.Date.AddDays(d)
                     Where Not weekend.Contains(day.DayOfWeek)
Dim countOfDays As Int32 = nonWeekendDays.Count()
```

If you have  `List(Of Date)` which contains the holidays you can add:

```
Where Not weekend.Contains(day.DayOfWeek) AndAlso Not holidays.Contains(day)
```

Comment: I have holiday on Access database
type of data is Datetime. How to I will add?